# Check if axes box is empty

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compare two images using Matlab. The problem is I'm getting the result even if there is nothing in the *Axes box*. I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is the error I'm getting[image]

And this is my Output screen

[image]

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the number of elements returned by [**findall**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html), when you pass the axes handle:

```
%// axes filled with plot
plot(1,1)
ax1 = gca;
out1 = numel(findall(ax1))

%// empty axes
axes
ax2 = gca;
out2 = numel(findall(ax2))
```

---

```
out1 =

     2


out2 =

     1
```

An empty axes object will return **1**, a filled one **at least 2**.